# getting a javascript error [object error] while using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

Im trying to use the DotNetOpenAuth library for openid authentication.

I have used the default project template that they provide and have successfully run the setup.aspx.

Now the problem is that when i get redirected from myopenid site back to my site, i get a javascript error[object error] in LoginFrame.aspx and the window closes.
Is it because i am working on localhost (cassini server) although i have white listed localhost in the web.config.

I need help to get this working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IE, yes it may just be because you're using localhost.  IE has a bug where redirects across zones screws up the javascripts.  Try a different browser than IE when using localhost to see if that works for you.  Once you go live, try IE again and it should work.